# Clickable link on div for Zen Cart products

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to work out how I can wrap a link around a div container so that I can make a product listing box a link to the product information page. I've tried playing around with the specials shown on the homepage but am getting nowhere.

Here is the code

```
 $list_box_contents = array();
while (!$specials_index->EOF) {
$products_price = zen_get_products_display_price($specials_index->fields['products_id']);

$products_description = zen_trunc_string(zen_clean_html(stripslashes(zen_get_products_description($specials_index->fields['products_id'], $_SESSION['languages_id']))), PRODUCT_LIST_DESCRIPTION); //To Display Product Desc 

$products_description = ltrim(substr($products_description, 0, 39) . '...'); //Trims and Limits the desc

if (!isset($productsInCategory[$specials_index->fields['products_id']])) $productsInCategory[$specials_index->fields['products_id']] = zen_get_generated_category_path_rev($specials_index->fields['master_categories_id']);

$specials_index->fields['products_name'] = zen_get_products_name($specials_index->fields['products_id']);
$list_box_contents[$row][$col] = array('params' => 'class="centerBoxContentsSpecials centeredContent back"' . ' ' . 'style="width:' . $col_width . '%;"',
'text' => (($specials_index->fields['products_image'] == '' and PRODUCTS_IMAGE_NO_IMAGE_STATUS == 0) ? '' : '   <div class="imagename"><div class="product_image">
<a href="' . zen_href_link(zen_get_info_page($specials_index->fields['products_id']), 'cPath=' . $productsInCategory[$specials_index->fields['products_id']] . '&products_id=' . (int)$specials_index->fields['products_id']) . '">' . zen_image(DIR_WS_IMAGES . $specials_index->fields['products_image'], $specials_index->fields['products_name'], SMALL_IMAGE_WIDTH, SMALL_IMAGE_HEIGHT) . '</a></div><div class="product_name">') . '<a href="' . zen_href_link(zen_get_info_page($specials_index->fields['products_id']), 'cPath=' . $productsInCategory[$specials_index->fields['products_id']] . '&products_id=' . $specials_index->fields['products_id']) . '">' . $specials_index->fields['products_name'] . '</a></div><div class="product_desc"><p class="s_desc">' . $products_description .'</p></div></div><div class="propricemain"><div class="prodprice">' . $products_price . '</div><div class="productbtn"><div class="mj-productdetailimage"><a href="' . zen_href_link(zen_get_info_page($specials_index->fields['products_id']), 'cPath=' . $productsInCategory[$specials_index->fields['products_id']] . '&products_id=' . (int)$specials_index->fields['products_id']) . '">More</a></div></div></div>');
```

I'm happy to use css or jquery to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping a div with a link sounds like you want to acomplish this:

```
<a href="product-page">
<div>
    Product information
</div>
```

While this may work on most browser, it's illegal (semantically incorrect), as links should not wrap divs.

My personal choice involves adding an onclick behavior to the div wich may look something like this:

```
<div style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="window.location='http://product-page';">
Product Information goes here.
</div>
```

If you still want to "wrap with a link" you may change your  for a .